# list custom permission

Tags: permissions, list-view, custom-list

In single list, I've 5 different city. I want user who belong to the city they can only be able to see that item. Example :-

```
User A - XXX City
User B - YYY City
User C - ZZZ City
User D - YYY City
```

So once user A will login he can see all the entry for his city only XXX city.

Comment: I guess you want only 'XXX' City for user A and not 'YYY'

Comment: How many entries can be available for a single user in the list ??

Comment: @Gaurravs-I've done the changes.. sorry for the confusion.. there is total 9 city in one list.. so user who belong to that city only can able to view the records

Comment: Roughly, how many cities would you have in the list?

Comment: @ Mihail - 9 cities..

Comment: ans  for my second question, also is there any people picker field in your list which represents the User? And If I am not wrong if 'A' logins in he should be able to see all user entries having same City as his like 'XXX'

Comment: yes..if 'A' logins in he should be able to see all user entries having same City.. and people picker field is there in this list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Options:**

**1) Item level security**

Set-level security item list. This allows to reach the maximum level, but it has two problems. It is complex to administer. On the other hand you can meet with the ceiling of security elements in a list.

**2) Item level security (c#)**

The second option is a variant of 1. You can set permissions from an event handler. The advantage is that you decrease manual labor. The downside is you have to develop in C # with Visual Studio.

**3) Folder level security**

Another option is to create within the list a folder for each user. And set permissions at the folder level. It is easier to manage. Remember that SharePoint supports three levels of permissions: list, folder or item. The disadvantage is the use of folders.

**4) Only filter**

Another option is to create a field of type person. Assign in that field to the person who can see the item. Then you create a view that filters using [ME]. This option UNSAFE. But it can be an alternative if high security is required.

**Others**

I think there may be other options using audience or workflows. Or some more complex with C #.

Comment: I think fourth one will work.. ONLY FILTER.. I will try this.. Thanks..

Comment: Good choice. But keep in mind that it is unsafe. Users can access the items that should not do from other views. Or directly to the screen.

Comment: Is it possible to assign different view of the same list to different group in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: No. But you can assign a group to a person field and then filter using [ME]